# i am not able to see my api after hosting on firebase,even after deploying it

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-hosting

here is my link to the image
to host my project on fire base,i did everything perfectly with a public folder in the project folder and put all the files in public folder, did the steps according to the official tutorial video from fire-base hosting,i tried this for multiple projects,it did show'deployed' but am not getting the actual result ,what am getting is this message when i open the site.

Welcome
Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

OPEN HOSTING DOCUMENTATION

i tried redoing the process by uninstalling and reinstalling to clear the fire base cache on my terminal but that does not work too.

here's the link to my image.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXjFQ.png

Comment: hey there, please don't link to external images - read here how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Both ".web.app" and ".firebaseapp.com" are valid domains for your hosted site.  .web.app is relatively new.  You can choose which one you want to use.

Comment: oh my bad,but i tried both the domains and both of them still give the same result(i.e the above image)i also checked my  html code,its not over written as some people might think.also,i did try uninstalling and re installing the fire base but it did not clear the laptop cache,which i thought would help me redo the process again.do you think you could still help me?thanks a lot for responding.